# How to create an object - has one :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  has_one   :card_rating
  has_one   :rating, through: :card_rating
end

class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :card_ratings
  has_many :cards, through: :card_ratings
end

class CardRating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :card
  belongs_to :rating
end
```

I want to do something along the lines of the following:

```
c = card.card_rating.new
c << rating
```

But there doesn't seem to be any association going on at all, because already at the first statement I receive the following error:

```
undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a join table for a one to many relation:

```
class Card
  belongs_to :rating
end

class Rating
  has_many :cards
end
```

Rather you would use `has_one :through` in case the domain dictates that the relation is indirect.

```
class Student
  belongs_to :school
  has_one :headmaster, through: :school
end

class School
  has_many :students
end

class Headmaster
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :students, through: :school
end
```